# Using sync with many to many relationship in laravel: PostgreSQL Pivot table doesn't update

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm getting this error whenever i try to sync an array of inputs to a pivot table:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: insert or update on table "items_option_parcel" 
violates foreign key constraint "items_option_id_fk_2971521" DETAIL: Key (items_option_id)=(0) is not present in table "items_options". (SQL: insert into "items_option_parcel" ("items_option_id", "parcel_id") values (0, 168))
```

here is a line of my controller:

```
$parcel->parcel_options()->sync($request->input('parcel_options', []));
```

function in the first model:

```
public function parcelOptionsParcels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Parcel::class);
    }
```

function in the 2nd model:

```
public function parcel_options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ItemsOption::class);
    }
```

Comment: are you passing a 0 in that input array? `parcel_options`?

Comment: no it should take the item option id which is not 0

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, i checked my pluck() function, i forgot to pluck the items options ID with their SKUs, that's why every time it says a 0 id is not present in the table because it wasn't getting fetched at all.

**I changed this:**

```
$parcel_options = ItemsOption::all()>pluck('item_option_sku')>prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');
```

**to this**

```
$parcel_options = 
ItemsOption::all()->pluck('item_option_sku','id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');
```